# Bokeh: Update a scatterplot from a checkboxgroup using CustomJS to filter source

Tags: javascript, python, plot, visualization, bokeh

I'm not very familiar with Java Script and need help from this great community!.

I'm trying to create a scatterplot with a Checkboxgroup attached to select different groups to plot. Dummy data is the following:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, CheckboxGroup, Column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd

data = dict(letter = ['A','A','B','C','B','B','A','C','C','B'], 
x = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3], 
y = ['10','20','10','30','10','40','10','30','10','40'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

source = ColumnDataSource(data)

plot = figure()
plot.circle('x', 'y', line_width = 2, source = source)
show(plot)
```

I would like to add a Checkboxgroup with letter as possible selections, and to plot the values of the selected letters only. It would be great if this could be done with Java Script to embbed in an HTML document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to accept the answer that was given if it works for you - I did for me

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, CheckboxGroup, CustomJS, BooleanFilter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

data = dict(letter=['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'],
            x=[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3],
            y=['10', '20', '10', '30', '10', '40', '10', '30', '10', '40'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

source = ColumnDataSource(data)

plot = figure()
active_letter = 'A'
f = BooleanFilter(booleans=[l == active_letter for l in data['letter']])
uniq_letters = sorted(set(data['letter']))
cg = CheckboxGroup(labels=uniq_letters, active=[uniq_letters.index(active_letter)])
cg.js_on_change('active',
                CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, f=f),
                         code="""\
                             const letters = cb_obj.active.map(idx => cb_obj.labels[idx]);
                             f.booleans = source.data.letter.map(l => letters.includes(l));
                             source.change.emit();
                         """))

plot.circle('x', 'y', line_width=2, source=source,
            view=CDSView(source=source, filters=[f]))

show(row(cg, plot))
```

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: The logic seems simple the Boolean filter is applied on the column you want to filter on, based on checkbox, which updates the active letter set. What I fail to see is when the "letters" are removed. Is active_letters generated from scratch everytime I select or unselect a box?

Comment: Actually, I was quick to reply... it is not working because the code is not updating the active letters list, which is necessary. This is a multiselect problem :(

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the active letters list"? If I check or uncheck any checkbox in the group, the plot changes for me. Nothing is checked - the plot is empty. Everything is checked - the full data is displayed.